# C# Generate dots on a panel

Tags: c#, combobox

I created a combobox and a panel so when the user clicks on a number from the combobox the number of dots appear randomly positioned on the panel with random colours. I tried searching for coding but can't manage to find what I truly need.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        //to randomize a color
        Color rC = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255));
        SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush(rC);
        g.FillEllipse(b1, e.X, e.Y, 30, 30);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
    }
}
```

I was using this at first but this is when the user clicks on the panel and the dots appear. I want them to randomly appear on the screen when the user presses a number from the combobox.

Comment: It's not quite clear what _is_ happening, and what you _want_ to happen. Could you elaborate a little to make your question more clear?

Comment: At the moment as I can see, you are not using the `combo-box` to populate the dots or whatever. Use combo-box event may be `textchanged` instead of form `MouseUp` event!! And don't use tags on Title!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create a `ComboBox` and attach it to `SelectedIndexChanged` event.
Populate your ComboBox with the desired values (I assume they are all integers, as you said so).

Now I would create this method to paint the dots with random position and color, numerous times, depends on the given parameter:

```
private void randomPaint(int numberOfTimes)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    Color rC;
    SolidBrush b1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
    {    
        // Randomize a color
        rC = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255));
        b1 = new SolidBrush(rC);
        // Paint with random position
        g.FillEllipse(b1, r.Next(this.Size.Width), r.Next(this.Size.Height), 30, 30);
    }
}
```

And add this code you the `SelectedIndexChanged` handler:

```
try{
    randomPaint(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle exception..
}
```